# Wired android connection

Tags: rasbperrypi, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!

I've got a small mobile robot with raspberry pi computer on board. I need to use some sensors and apparently most of them are included in a standard android phone. Therefore i've been thinking of mounting such device on the robot. I know there is quite easy way to communicate phone and ros-enabled computer via wifi, but since the phone will be an integral part of the robot i'd prefer faster and more reliable cable connection. So here comes my question:

Is there a possibility to connect android to the ros master with usb cable?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/134336/wired-android-connection/) by [grzebyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3912/grzebyk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2014-02-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some phones can act as usb host, in this way you can for instance use a mouse on your phone. Perhaps it is also possible to connect a usb ethernet adapter.
Or run ROS on the phone and use an arduino with android ADK interface:
http://www.adafruit.com/products/563

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2014-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [grzebyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3912/grzebyk/) on 2014-03-12**:
Thank you. This arduino has all the required components. Adding this module helps a lot and make everything easier:)